# How do I set an arbitrary axis for anime.js rotation?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, anime.js

Say I want to rotate a line with the midpoint(x='250', y='250') of the line as the axis for the following:

```js
const line = document.querySelector('.line');

anime({
    targets: 'line',
    rotateY: '360deg'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.min.js" integrity="sha256-BuxrUdr/4YoztQLxT6xmdO6hSQw2d6BtBUY1pteGds4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<svg width='500' height='500'>
    <rect x='0', y='0' width="500px" height='500px' fill='black'></rect>
    <circle cx='250' cy='250' r='250' fill='white'></circle>
    <line class='line' x1='250' y1='0' x2='250' y2='500' stroke='black' stroke-width='10px'></line>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to assign an arbitrary axis for a rotation?